# Laravel solve correct return class definitation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In one class which i used in `Laravel` i have this method:

```php
public function submit(): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
{
    $this->validate($this->rules);
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password])) {
        $this->emmitMessage('', 'Your Welcome', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('administrator','en');
    } else {
        $this->emmitMessage('', 'Username or password is incorrect', 'error');
    }
}

private function emmitMessage($title = '', $text = '', $type = 'info')
{
    $this->emit('registerNotification', [
        // ...
    ]);
}
```

in this method which i have `return redirect()->route('administrator','en')` that's instance of `\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` and after successful login i get this error:

```
App\Http\Livewire\Auth\LoginComponent::submit(): 
    Return value must be of type Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse,
    Livewire\Redirector returned
```

i think this is correct but i can't fix this error

Comment: Are you sure this error appears on successful login? there might be a chance that it falls in else part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Laravel Liwewire yet, but I believe it somehow overrides default Laravel redirection system, so:

```
return redirect()->route('administrator','en');
```

is returning custom Liwewire redirect response.

That's why probably instead of:

```
public function submit(): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
```

you should try with just:

```
public function submit()
```

or

```
public function submit(): \Livewire\Redirector
```

to make it work

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` was what I required with the return type defined as `myControllerMethod(Request $request): RedirectResponse`. Coming from Java and Python to several projects on CakePHP, I'm really struggling badly with L10, I'd expect a framework to be intelligent, intuitive and reasonably strict but Laravel is way too careless. I'll probably not touch laravel again after this project is over.

Comment: By the way, I could easily leave out the return type for that function but I'd rather follow the L10 convention and of course because I'm used to do that from Java